# Reshaping tensors in a 3D numpy matrix

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm essentially trying to accomplish [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055493/numpy-convert-an-array-to-a-triangular-matrix) and then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250729/how-to-convert-triangle-matrix-to-square-in-numpy) but with a 3D matrix, say (128,128,60,6). The 4th dimension is an array vector that represents the diffusion array at that voxel, e.g.:

```
d[30,30,30,:] = [dxx, dxy, dxz, dyy, dyz, dzz] = D_array
```

Where dxx etc. are diffusion for a particular direction. D_array can also be seen as a triangular matrix (since dxy == dyx etc.). So I can use those 2 other answers to get from D_array to D_square, e.g.

```
D_square = [[dxx, dxy, dxz], [dyx, dyy, dyz],[dzx, dzy, dzz]]
```

I can't seem to figure out the next step however - how to apply that unit transformation of a D_array into D_square to the whole 3D volume.

Here's the code snippet that works on a single tensor:

```
#this solves an linear eq. that provides us with diffusion arrays at each voxel in a 3D space
D = np.einsum('ijkt,tl->ijkl',X,bi_plus)

#our issue at this point is we have a vector that represents a triangular matrix.
# first make a tri matx from the vector, testing on unit tensor first
D_tri = np.zeros((3,3))
D_array = D[30][30][30]
D_tri[np.triu_indices(3)] = D_array
# then getting the full sqr matrix
D_square = D_tri.T + D_tri
np.fill_diagonal(D_square, np.diag(D_tri))
```

So what would be the numpy-way of formulating that unit transformation of the Diffusion tensor to the whole 3D volume all at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one using `row, col` indices from `triu_indices` for indexing along last two axes into an initialized output array -

```
def squareformnd_rowcol_integer(ar, n=3):
    out_shp = ar.shape[:-1] + (n,n)
    out = np.empty(out_shp, dtype=ar.dtype)

    row,col = np.triu_indices(n)

    # Get a "rolled-axis" view with which the last two axes come to the front
    # so that we could index into them just like for a 2D case
    out_rolledaxes_view = out.transpose(np.roll(range(out.ndim),2,0))    

    # Assign permuted version of input array into rolled output version
    arT = np.moveaxis(ar,-1,0)
    out_rolledaxes_view[row,col] = arT
    out_rolledaxes_view[col,row] = arT
    return out
```

**Approach #2**

Another one with the last two axes merged into one and then indexing with linear indices -

```
def squareformnd_linear_integer(ar, n=3):
    out_shp = ar.shape[:-1] + (n,n)
    out = np.empty(out_shp, dtype=ar.dtype)

    row,col = np.triu_indices(n)
    idx0 = row*n+col
    idx1 = col*n+row

    ar2D = ar.reshape(-1,ar.shape[-1])
    out.reshape(-1,n**2)[:,idx0] = ar2D
    out.reshape(-1,n**2)[:,idx1] = ar2D
    return out
```

**Approach #3**

Finally altogether a new method using `masking` and should be better with performance as most `masking` based ones are when it comes to indexing -

```
def squareformnd_masking(ar, n=3):
    out = np.empty((n,n)+ar.shape[:-1] , dtype=ar.dtype)

    r = np.arange(n)
    m = r[:,None]<=r

    arT = np.moveaxis(ar,-1,0)
    out[m] = arT
    out.swapaxes(0,1)[m] = arT
    new_axes = range(out.ndim)[2:] + [0,1]
    return out.transpose(new_axes)
```

Timings on `(128,128,60,6)` shaped random array -

```
In [635]: ar = np.random.rand(128,128,60,6)

In [636]: %timeit squareformnd_linear_integer(ar, n=3)
     ...: %timeit squareformnd_rowcol_integer(ar, n=3)
     ...: %timeit squareformnd_masking(ar, n=3)
10 loops, best of 3: 103 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 103 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 53.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: It does work - although that makes me realize that my go-to formulation tends to be vector addressing (more along the lines of Daniel's answer). I need to study up on that a bit (integer/boolean indexing). I kinda get the gist of it but not the details (yet). Interesting.

Comment: @LogicOnAbstractions In the edited post, check out app#1, might be easier. Try out with  a smaller data, let's say - `ar = np.random.randint(11,99,(3,6))` and  break down each step.

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized way to do it:

```
# Gets the triangle matrix
d_tensor = np.zeros(128, 128, 60, 3, 3)
triu_idx = np.triu_indices(3)
d_tensor[:, :, :, triu_idx[0], triu_idx[1]] = d
# Make it symmetric
diagonal = np.zeros(128, 128, 60, 3, 3)
idx = np.arange(3)
diagonal[:, :, :, idx, idx] = d_tensor[:, :, :, idx, idx]
d_tensor = np.transpose(d_tensor, (0, 1, 2, 4, 3)) + d_tensor - diagonal
```

Comment: This almost works, except for the fact that it doubles elements on the diagognale (which is why I was using np.fill after my transpose).

This is intuitively what I was aiming for - my main misunderstanding was about the indexing of d_tensor when assigning to d

Comment: But then if you do that the way you currently edited it, you're halving the non-diagonale elements.

Calling .fill_diagonale has the advantage of leaving all the elements that are fine as-is (e.g. the non-diago ones) but just switching the diago elements that have been doubled by the transpose by the old values, non double.

I guess we could also do some /2 but masked by i==j (e.g. diago indexes). I'm just writing this of others reading not going wrong on that detail.

Comment: I do intuitively prefer this style, but I accepted the other one because it's overall more through (checks for types as well and more generics on dimensions). thanks for the answer though